# How to change orientation of object and location?

Tags: origin, axis

[image] My object (the tiny donut) seems to be floating but I wanted to place my object at the center like how the box is centered with grid axis in the image below:

[image]

Is it also possible to change the orientation of my donut so that it would face upwards?

[image]

Comment: first of all try alt G and alt R, it might bring it back to the center and it might reset its rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put objects back into *World origin*, you need to reset their transforms.
You can do it for both Donut and Icing at once.

1. Shift Drop the Icing onto the Donut in the outliner. So they move together.
2. Select your Donut and clear all transforms one by one. This will put both in center.
3. Select Icing and clear Parent relationship (Alt+P). Then go *Object > Apply > All Transforms.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: okay so I went to object and cleared the location and rotation but for some reason it's still floating above the axis rather than being centered on it. I'm pretty sure I did something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: Okay :). In that case, consider sharing your file. There could be multiple reasons and I'm not very good at guessing.

Comment: Done! I uploaded it on blend exchange.

Comment: Hey :). It has a simple solution, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you :) that worked

Answer (score 0):

Center the cursor in case it is not centered <kbd>Shift+C</kbd>

then

Select the donut and press and hold <kbd>Shift+S</kbd> and move the mouse up to the option "Selection to cursor".

Simple as that!